# Jinja2 + pdfkit not preserving HTML styling / bootstrap grid layout

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, jinja2, pdfkit

PDFKIT seems to be misinterpreting some of the Bootstrap CSS / div css and is forcing breaks between each HTML element.

Using the following html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>


    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>{{-variable_a-}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>{{-variable_b-}}</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <p>{{-variable_c-}}</p>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

and the following python code to

a) substitute the variable values with jinja2

b) generate HTML->PDF

```
import jinja2
import pdfkit

context = {
   'variable_a': 'a',
   'variable_b': 'b',
   'variable_c': 'c',
}

template_loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader('./')
template_env = jinja2.Environment(loader=template_loader)

template = template_env.get_template('scripts/template.html')
output = template.render(context)

with open('scripts/output.html', 'w') as of:
    of.write(output)

config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf')
pdfkit.from_file('scripts/output.html', 'scripts/output pdf.pdf', configuration=config)
```

I have tried:

- bootstrap in a local css file instead of in the link tag
- using page options with pdfkit (a4, margins, etc..)
- manually forcing certain styles in the html file
- inserting 'sm', 'md' and 'lg' options for bootstrap references

The output still always forces elements one after the other vertically on new "lines" and does not preserve the column / grid layout.

From the HTML, expected output style:

[image]

Actual PDF output:

[image]

Would greatly appreciate any more suggestions to try! I've seen usage of bootstrap with jinja/pdfkit so not sure what is going wrong!